# Controlling internal and external autoreplies

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, mailbox

When I set mailboxsettigs|automaticRepliesSetting|status using MSGraph (for a shared mailbox) it seems to only affect the setting for internal recipients and there seems no syntax for dealing with internal/external recipients.   What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "for a shared mailbox"? Does it mean that for your default mailbox  the automatic reply is sent to both internal and external recipients but for a shared mailbox the reply is sent only to internal recipients?

Comment: I guess I may not have worded that as well as I might.  I was merely trying to provide full information and saying that the mail box I was changing the auto replies for wasn't mine, wasn't another users, but a shared mailbox, just in case it was a germane fact.

Answer (score 0):

For external recipients you need to also set `externalAudience` to `all`.

```
PATCH /users/{id}/mailboxSettings

"automaticRepliesSetting": {
        "status": "scheduled",
        "externalAudience": "all",
        "scheduledStartDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2023-02-15T02:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "scheduledEndDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2023-02-16T02:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
    "internalReplyMessage": "<html>\n<body>\n<p>I'm out<br>\n</p></body>\n</html>\n",
    "externalReplyMessage": "<html>\n<body>\n<p>I'm out<br>\n</p></body>\n</html>\n"
    }
```